# What is this hallmark on silverware?

Tags: identification, silver, silver-hallmark

My family stumbled upon another piece of silverware.  Sadly we cannot identify the [silver mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_hallmarks) nor do we know where the piece comes from.  Someone pointed out that it might be Persian. But that did not help us at all.

The hallmark consists of 3 symbols (from left to right, as seen in the picture):

1. ???
2. A Bell
3. ??? <- might be the number 900 ?

Maybe some of you fine people could point us in the right direction.
Please have a look at the picture and share your knowledge.

Thanks

[image: Three symbols in silver]

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic... maybe try https://www.silver-collector.com/

Comment: The same three marks appear to be discussed [in this thread](https://www.925-1000.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23514) of a third-party forum, where they are described as Egyptian, and further details are given. The middle mark is apparently a lotus flower, not a bell (image is upside down here).

Comment: @njuffa Those are _clearly_ not 'the same'! But thx, they are similar, & it confirms my nervous reading of the pic here (upside down, ~Hieroglyphs, Lotus; here the '1st' (or last) may be Arabic (nun?)?). Fragender: could you upload an image with more detail (+ 180° rotated)?

Comment: @njuffa Good call on that third-party forum thread. Looks like the first two symbols are the same, indicating .900 silver, but the third (the date) may be different.

Comment: https://www.silvercollection.it/EGYPTSILVERHALLMARKS.html may be of some help.

Answer (score 5):

Credit to Shoover, the [page he links to](https://www.silvercollection.it/EGYPTSILVERHALLMARKS.html) has this well down it:

[image]

which looks to be the same as yours.  Interpreted it is:

- [Beni Souef, .900 fine]
- [Silver]
- [1992]

(I would probably have only commented, but had to raise this to an answer to show the illustration)